# unicode code points to utf-8 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I downloaded tweets in Urdu language. When I read the csv file using pandas in python, the tweet is shown as follows:

**Sample tweet text**

[Unicode code point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaaaj.png)
I want to convert this into utf-8.

Comment: use `.encode('utf-8')`. But why would you want to remove it anyways?

Comment: You could use `str('yourtext')` or `'{}'.format('yourtext')` or like Ganesh said, `'sometext'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Ok so after the edit, `.encode('utf-8')` should do the trick either ways

Comment: Using .encode('utf-8') throws error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-ea1e0f35c484> in <module>()
----> 1 print urdutweets.iloc[1]['text'].encode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 544: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Morb {}'.format('yourtext') has no effect. It is still printing the string in the form of unicode codes

Comment: You *don't* want to convert it into UTF-8. You want to convert the `<U+00FF>` escapes into regular Python strings.

Comment: Have you tried .encode('utf-8', "ignore")

Comment: You're not doing something silly like `less file-utf8.txt | python` to botch the input like that, are you?

Comment: Ok so if you do `print(u'\xf1')`, you get: `ñ`, which is basically not ascii and it works. So why do you wish to convert exactly? Like I worked with Hindi recently and had no need to convert and worked with it natively, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @HariKrishnan yes. It is also giving the same error as with .encode('utf-8')

Comment: how about this ?.encode("utf-8", "ignore").decode('utf-8', "ignore")

Comment: it is still not working @HariKrishnan

Comment: @GaneshK I have vector embeddings in the format of utf-8 therefore I need to replace unicode codepoints with their utf-8 representations

Comment: Sorry , i meant this .decode("utf-8", "ignore").encode('utf-8', "ignore")

Comment: `your_message.decode("iso8859-6")` ?

Answer (score -1):

When you are writing the tweet data to a file use `.decode('utf-8')`
And when you try to read data from that file use `.encode('utf-8')`

Here I am posting an example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
string1 = "آکاش کمار"
string2 = string1.decode('utf-8')
string3 = string2.encode('utf-8')
print(string3)
```

Comment: The tweet data in the image looks nothing like what you assume.